# Comparison of structure pointer address not working

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If condition inside the `findset` is not giving correct comparison.  It is always shows not equal.

Where did I make a mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
  struct node *p;
  int rank;
};

void makeset(struct node x) {
  x.p = &x;
  x.rank = 0;
}

void findset(struct node x) {
  if (x.p == &x) {
    printf("It worked bro\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int nv, ne;
  nv = 4;
  ne = 5;
  for (int i = 0; i < nv; ++i) {
    struct node i;
    makeset(i);
    findset(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: `struct node i;` inside `for (int i = 0; i < nv; ++i)` probably isn't doing what you think it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way your code will ever work. You ignore the fact that C uses pass by value -- meaning that when you pass a `stuct node` as a parameter to your function, (e.g. `void makeset(struct node x)`) the function receives a *copy of* the `struct` with its very own (and very different) address than the original struct in `main()`.

So when you pass your struct to `void findset(struct node x)`, there is no way `if (x.p == &x)` will ever test true -- because there is no requirement that the address of the copy of `x` received by `void findset(struct node x)` and stored in `p` is the same address as the copy of `x` that got passed to `void makeset(struct node x)`.

Your second problem is your declare the same struct `i` 4 times in:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nv; ++i)
 {
    struct node i;
    makeset(i);
    findset(i);
 }
```

You already have a variable `i` declared in your `for` loop. When you make the declaration `struct node i;`, you are not creating `struct node 0;, struct node 1; ...`, you are simply creating `struct node i;` 4 times. (no variable can be named a number or begin with a number in C) The `i` in your `struct node` declaration *shadows* the loop counter declaration of `i`. Add the warning `-Wshadow` to your compile string as a standard part of your compiler warnings.

What you need to do is declare an array of `struct node` if your want to be able to fill your nodes separately. For the purpose of this example, you could declare a struct with the same name 4-times - but that is rather limited to the use within your `for` loop (as your struct is declared *within* the for loop block, it is destroyed (the stack memory released for reused) each and every iteration of the loop. To prevent that from occurring, you can declare an array of 4 `struct node` before you enter your loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NNODES 4    /* if you need a constant, define one */
...
int main (void) {

    struct node nodes[NNODES] = {{ .p = NULL }};
```

Next, to have any chance of `findset` ever being able to compare the original address of the `struct node` you pass as a parameter, you must pass the **address of** the struct, instead of the struct itself. That way, even though the function receives a pointer to a `struct node`, the value contained is the original address of the struct from the calling function (`main()` here)

So you need to change both function declarations to:

```
void makeset (struct node *x)
```

and

```
void findset (struct node *x)
```

You will also need to use the `->` operator to access the members instead of the `'.'` operator.

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NNODES 4    /* if you need a constant, define one */

struct node {
    struct node *p;
    int rank;
};

void makeset (struct node *x)
{
    x->p = x;
    x->rank = 0;
}

void findset (struct node *x)
{
    if (x->p == x)
        printf ("It worked bro\n");
}

int main (void) {

    struct node nodes[NNODES] = {{ .p = NULL }};

    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++) {
        makeset (&nodes[i]);
        findset (&nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

(**note:** how the *address of* each `struct node` is passed to each function in `main()`, e.g. `makeset (&nodes[i]);`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_ptr_addr
It worked bro
It worked bro
It worked bro
It worked bro
```

It works now bro...

If you did really intend to declare a single `stuct node` in your `for` loop that is created and destroyed each iteration, then it works the same for a single struct as well -- you still have to pass the *address of* the struct to each function, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NNODES 4    /* if you need a constant, define one */

struct node {
    struct node *p;
    int rank;
};

void makeset (struct node *x)
{
    x->p = x;
    x->rank = 0;
}

void findset (struct node *x)
{
    if (x->p == x)
        printf ("It worked bro\n");
}

int main (void) {

    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++) {
        struct node somenode = { .p = NULL };
        makeset (&somenode);
        findset (&somenode);
    }
}
```

(the output is the same)

Hopefully, you now understand that when you pass a variable as a parameter, the called function receives a copy of the variable holding the original value. And, if you want to pass the address of the variable, then you have to pass the address as a pointer to insure that that original address is available within the called function (and any changes made visible back in the caller).

Answer (score 2):

```
void findset(struct node x)
 {
    if (x.p == &x)
    {
```

that `x` is a copy of the one passed in... x is always brand new and `&x` wont match any previous address.

Note that this is true not just of structs but all values...

```
int i = 3;

void f( int j)
{
    // &j != &i
    // j == i
    // j and I have the same value, but different address
}

int main()
{
   f(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, you're passing in the value instead of the actual variable. The solution here is one of the reasons pointers are so powerful, you can just pass the pointer for the actual variable you want to change. For example:

```
void foo(){

    int i = 8;
    bar(&i);
}

int bar(int* i){
    return *i * 2;
}
```

That should work better for you